# What is the meaning of "in" and "out" in iptables -L -v

Tags: linux, iptables

When I run iptables -L -v, part of the output I get is the following:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
```

What do the in and out columns mean in this case? I gather that they are related to network devices, but I don't know if a request originates from in and goes to out or vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're input or output interfaces.

```
man iptables | awk '/in/ && /interface/'
```

In:

> Name of an interface via which a packet was received

Out:

> Name of an interface via which a packet is going to be sent

Comment: What do they mean in the OUTPUT chain?

Comment: You might have different interfaces which you want to control them, `-o` only works for FORWARD, OUTPUT and POSTROUTING while `-i` is for INPUT, FORWARD and PREROUTING changes, let's say I want to block all traffics from x.x.x.1 in input chain only from enp3s0 and not enp3s1 now I can use `-i` to specify `enp3s0`